# marklogic javascript json does json documents have a namespace

Tags: javascript, json, marklogic

I am trying to grasp the javascript and JSON documents in marklogic.
Does the JSON documents support namespaces and how do you implement one: that is add your own content. can some provide a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON standard doesn't have namespaces.

Some people argue for ignoring properties that aren't recognized and for wrapping or renaming as needed to avoid naming collisions when composing a JSON document from multiple inputs.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: I thought so. i was wondering that the Marklogic would have some kind of work around

Comment: If you need namespaces, there are data formats that do support them, cough, cough, *XML*